# How to load huge amount of data into R?

Tags: r

I have data of 20 variables and 633,000 observations in xls file. So when i try to load this data into R i get following error.

```
Error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): Java heap space
```

I tried using

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m")
```

But still same error.

I tried using `XLConnect` package.

```
wb = loadWorkbook("alldata.xls")
```

the size of data file is 63mb and my RAM size is 4GB

Comment: What are you using in order to load it into R? I'm not familiar with error. And that data is far away from being *huge* unless you have 512 MB RAM or something. Try converting your file to `.csv` and read it using `data.table::fread` instead. OR try [the readxl](https://github.com/hadley/readxl) package on your original xls file. I think it avoid Java dependency

Comment: Also this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r

Comment: Save it as a `.csv` and use `read.csv`

Comment: Or save it as csv and use `fread(...)` in the `data.table` package. Extremely fast.